# Direct sum from basis of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Suppose that ${x_1, x_2, · · · , x_n}$ is a basis for $V$ . For some $1 ≤ r ≤ n$ let $M = <x_1, · · · , x_r>$ and
$N = <x_{r+1}, · · · , x_n>.$ Show that $V = M ⊕ N.$

So I need help proving this out. I think I need to show that $v$ of $V$ is given by $x+y=v$ for $x$ element of $M$ and $y$ of $N$. And I also need to show that this intersection is just the empty set. I need help articulating the proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given that $m \in M$ can be expressed as a linear combination of its basis elements, let $m \in M$, then:
$$m = \sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_i x_i$$
In the same way $n \in N$ can be expressed as:
$$n = \sum_{i=r+1}^{n}\lambda_i x_i$$
Now, we can sum $m + n$, as:
$$m + n = \sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_i x_i + \sum_{i=r+1}^{n}\lambda_i x_i$$
Applying properties of sum, we can do
$$m + n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i x_i = v \in V$$
And this sum is unique because it is expressed as linear combination of elements of basis of V.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $x_1, ..., x_n$ is a basis of $V$ they're all linearly independent - so in particular we have $\alpha_1 x_1 + ... + \alpha_r x_r + \alpha_{r+1} x_{r+1} + ... + \alpha_n x_n = 0 \implies \alpha_1=...=\alpha_n=0$.
Now assume that $$\sum_{j=1}^r\alpha_j x_j =: v \in M$$ is also an element of $N$. Since $x_{r+1},...,x_n$ is a basis of $N$ there are $\beta_j$ such that $v = \sum_{j=r+1}^n \beta_j x_j$. So we have
$$
v = \sum_{j=1}^r\alpha_j x_j = \sum_{j=r+1}^n \beta_j x_j \\
\iff \sum_{j=1}^r\alpha_j x_j - \sum_{j=r+1}^n \beta_j x_j = 0
$$
Note that if this is true for any nonzero $\alpha_j, \beta_j$ then the $x_j$ can't have been linearly independent and thus not a basis of $V$ and we have a contradiction. If on the other hand the coefficients are all $0$ we have precisely the case that $v$ is the zero vector. Thus we've shown that $M \cap N = \{0\}$.

The next part is trivial: assume you have some $v \in V$. Since $x_1,...,x_n$ is a basis there are (unique) coefficients $\alpha_j$ such that $v = \sum_j^n \alpha_j x_j$. Just decompose this sum into two parts or $j=1,...,r$ and $j={r+1},...,n$, note that those parts are in $M$ and $N$ and you're done.